# Reference column by id in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple duplicate columns (due to joins) If I try to call them by alias, I get an ambiguous reference error:

> Reference 'customers_id' is ambiguous, could be: customers_id#13, customers_id#85, customers_id#130

Is there a way to reference a column in a Scala Spark Dataframe by it's order in the Dataframe or by numeric ID, not by an alias? Sanitized names suggest that columns do have an id assigned (13, 85, 130 in the example below)

LATER EDIT:

I found out that I can reference a specific column by the original dataframe it was in. But, while I can use `OriginalDataframe.customer_id` in select function, the `withColumnRename` function only accepts string alias so I cannot rename the duplicate column in the final `dataframe`.

So, I guess the end question is:
Is there a way to reference a column that has a duplicate alias, that works with all functions that require a string alias as argument?

LATER EDIT 2:

Renaming seemed to have worked via adding a new column and dropping one of the current ones:

```
joined_dataframe = joined_dataframe.withColumn("renamed_customers_id", original_dataframe("customers_id")).drop(original_dataframe("customers_id"))
```

But, I'd like to keep my question open:

Is there a way to reference a column that has a duplicate alias (so, using something other than alias) in a way that all functions which expect a string alias accept it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get out of such a situation would be to create a new Dataframe using the old one's `rdd`, but with a new schema, where you can name each column as you'd like. This, of course, requires you to explicitly describe the entire schema, including the type of each column. As long as the new schema you provides matches the number of columns, and the column types, of the old Dataframe - this should work.

For example - starting with a Dataframe with two columns named `type` we can rename them `type1` and `type2`:

```
df.show()
// +---+----+----+
// | id|type|type|
// +---+----+----+
// |  1| AAA| aaa|
// |  1| BBB| bbb|
// +---+----+----+

val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, new StructType()
  .add("id", IntegerType)
  .add("type1", StringType)
  .add("type2", StringType)
)

newDF.show()
// +---+-----+-----+
// | id|type1|type2|
// +---+-----+-----+
// |  1|  AAA|  aaa|
// |  1|  BBB|  bbb|
// +---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have 15+ columns in the Dataframe so redefining the schema would take a while. I found another way to rename it by adding a new column and dropping the current one. Takes less writing but I'm wondering about efficiency. Is what you are proposing more efficient?

Comment: Not sure - your solution might cost a bit more memory due to the temporary duplication of data, but I'm not familiar with the inner workings enough to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is join, ı use python.

```
h1.createOrReplaceTempView("h1")
h2.createOrReplaceTempView("h2")
h3.createOrReplaceTempView("h3")

joined1 = h1.join(h2, (h1.A == h2.A) & (h1.B == h2.B) & (h1.C == h2.C), 'inner')
```

Result dataframe columns:

```
A B Column1 Column2 A B Column3 ...
```

I don't like this , but join must be implement like this:

```
joined1 = h1.join(h2, [*argv], 'inner')
```

We assume argv = ["A", "B", "C"]

Result columns:

```
A B column1 column2 column3 ...
```